# How to add style to a image when you hover over it, in asp.net website

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, css

I have a image in my website, How can I add style to it so that it looks like a real button. now when I click it or move the mouse over it there is no changes to the image. when click or the mouse it over it how can I add style to it. Thanks

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="Img_ComposeMessage" PostBackUrl="~/SendMessage.aspx" ImageUrl="Styles/Images/ComposeMessage.png"
                            runat="server"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like something you can easily accomplish with JavaScript / jQuery; just hook into the mouseover event and change the image then.

If you're worried about flash of unstyled content, you could switch to using css background/spriting for your image along with an asp:linkbutton instead of an asp:imagebutton

Here's a quick tutorial to get you started - http://www.learningjquery.com/2007/02/quick-tip-set-hover-class-for-anything

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Javascript and/or CSS styling to change the ImageButtons properties.

Client Side javascript method calls can be added to the ImageButton's [OnClientClick](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.imagebutton.onclientclick.aspx) Property.

To ensure you have a static ID property on the control when rendered, for use with CSS effect or JQuery, use the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) Property, set it to Static, the ID property you define with be rendered.

Comment: Just a note that the ClientIDMode property is only available in asp.net 4.0